# How do I do a kivy app with a button creating a tuple?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, button, kivy, screen

I've done some simple coding creating a tuple from generation of def get_data function, purely randomized. My goal is to have a screen with the three buttons that I can push, each of them generating randomized values in a df to be presented in the same screen...randomized data is generated like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def get_data(size=1000):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['col1'] = np.random.randint(0, 50, size)
    df['col2'] = np.random.randint(0, 50, size)
    df['col3'] = np.random.rand(1000)
    print("df")
    return df


print(get_data(size=1000))

one = get_data()

one = one[(one.col3) < 1 & (one.col3 > 0.9)]

test8 = tuple(one.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
result = test8

print("\nresult")
print(result)
```

How do I create a kivy app to generate random numbers for each of the df's in my get_data function? Generating a screen pushing a button for each of the col's above, this would generate tuples in a display of some sort, e.g. like the ones on calculators...

Tried this, but no screen appears:

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

kv = '''
<Launch>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size:(80,80)
            size_hint:(None,None)
            text:"Click me"
            on_press: root.generate_random_data()

'''

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Test(App):

    def press(self, size):
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['col1'] = np.random.randint(0, 50, size)
        df['col2'] = np.random.randint(0, 50, size)
        df['col3'] = np.random.rand(1000)
        # print("Pressed")
        return df

    def build(self):
        butt=Button(text="Click")
        butt.bind(on_press=self.press) #dont use brackets while calling function
        return butt

Test().run()
```

Got this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\...\.\...\tuple_test_new_1.py", line 60, in <module>
     Test().run()
TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer
```

Any support from kivy sharks out there would much appreciated...;o)

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked out looks something like this:

```
class MyDf(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
        a['col1'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, size=1000))
        a['col2'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 50, size=1000))
        a['col3'] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000))
        self.df = tuple(a.itertuples(index=False, name=None))

    def press(self,instance):
        print(self.df)

    def build(self):
        butt=Button(text="Click")
        butt.bind(on_press=self.press) #dont use brackets while calling function
        return butt

MyDf().run()
```